# Search for all emails sharing common message-id in the references field using IMAP

Tags: email, search, imap, imaplib, email-client

I want to get all the emails under the same thread using IMAP.

I used the following code but It doesn't return any email IDs.

```
search_criteria = f'HEADER REFERENCES "{message_id}"'
result, data = imap.search(None, search_criteria)
```

I cannot search like this, as another email can have the same subject name.

```
mail.search(None, '(SUBJECT "Sending email using SMTP")')
```

What should the search criteria be for fetching them using references?

```
Suppose,
Email1 is in the inbox.
And Email2 is replied to Email1. So, Email2 has the message-id of Email1 in the references field of itself.
In the same way Email3 is replied to Email2. 
So, Email3 has message-ids of Email1 and Email2 in the references field of itself.
And Email4 has message-ids of Email1, Email2 and Email3 in the references field.
```

So, I want to get Email2, Email3, Email4 When I search using `IMAP`.

What should be the `search criteria`?

Comment: It’s possible your server just doesn’t have a sophisticated enough search parser.  You may have to cache headers locally, or see if your server had the THREADING extension